# onsenUIをbrowserifyでrequireするには？

Tags: onsen-ui, angularjs, browserify

onsenUIをbrowserifyで使うには、どのようにrequireすればよいのでしょうか？

ons = require 'onsenui'

上の記述だけでは、consoleに
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
というエラーが出ます。

onsenはbowerで入れました。
他にもrequireしなければならない依存しているものがありますか？

Comment: 4224行目の
 document.documentElement

ここでエラーが発生しているようです。

window.Modernizrで定義されている即時関数の中ですので、ここがbrowserifyで引っかかっているようです。Modernizrのエラーでしょうか？

gulpからbowerでインストールしたものを、debowerifyを使ってrequireしており、onsenuiのverは1.3.2です。